# Why compiler gives error?

Tags: cuda, compiler-errors, thrust

```
thrust::host_vector<int> A;
thrust::host_vector<int> B;

int rand_from_0_to_100_gen(void)
{
     return rand() % 100;
}


__host__ void generateVector(int count) {


    thrust::host_vector<int> A(count);
    thrust::generate(A.begin(),A.end(),rand_from_0_to_100_gen);

    thrust::host_vector<int> B(count);
    thrust::generate(B.begin(),B.end(),rand_from_0_to_100_gen);
}

__host__ void displayVector(int count){

    void generateVector(count);

    cout << A[1];


}
```

In above code, why i cannot display vector values? it gives error at

```
void generateVector(count);
```

that says `incomplete is not allowed` Why? What's wrong here? What might be the possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function `generateVector` incorrectly inside the function `displayVector`.  It should be like this:

```
generateVector(count);
```

Also, you are creating vectors `A` and `B` inside the function `generateVector` which will be local to the function and `thrust::generate` will operate on these local vectors. The global vectors `A` and `B` would not be modified. You should remove the local vectors to achieve what you want. Instead call `host_vector::resize` for for the global vectors `A` and `B` to allocate memory.

The final code should be like this:

```
thrust::host_vector<int> A;
thrust::host_vector<int> B;

int rand_from_0_to_100_gen(void)
{
    return rand() % 100;
}

__host__ void generateVector(int count) 
{
    A.resize(count);
    thrust::generate(A.begin(),A.end(),rand_from_0_to_100_gen);

    B.resize(count);
    thrust::generate(B.begin(),B.end(),rand_from_0_to_100_gen);
}

__host__ void displayVector(int count)
{
    generateVector(count);
    cout << A[1]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help in generateVector and displayVector function there is one more parameter defined as int * hData what might be that?

Comment: there is no hData here. guy defined this function by putting int * hData i dont know why